# VS 2010 Print form on 8.5 x 11 paper

Tags: .net, visual-studio, printing

I'm trying to print a form in VS 2010 on 8.5 x 11 paper. The problem with using the PrintForm is that if the computer's resolution is less than 1100 (which it basically always is) then it cuts off the bottom part of the paper that is more than the computer's resolution. I've tried so many different things: drawing part of it, drawing the whole thing...I've had very little success so far.
I'm sure that I'm not the only one trying to print onto 8.5 x 11 - how does everyone handle this? Do you print natively in .net or do you send the information somewhere else to print? 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Printing a form and trying to fill the paper in general makes very little sense.  The result is always ugly with every one pixel of the form turned into a 6x6 blob of ink on paper.  Especially text is not nice to look at unless you have really long arms, the ClearType anti-aliasing doesn't work at all on paper.  But you can,  you are just using the default scaling mode.  Simply use e.Graphics.ScaleTransform() in your PrintPage event handler to resize it any way you want.

Comment: If printing a form doesn't make sense, how would you go about it? I need information printed - which third party would you send it to, to print? I looked into the ScaleTransform method, but that's not what I need. I don't need to make the controls bigger or smaller - I just need certain controls to print at the bottom of the paper.